# Why does my edit screen suddenly have such a buggy interface?

Tags: wp-admin, css

I've attached an image link to show how WordPress displays my *Post Edit* screen.

Most of the time the *Post Edit* screen is displayed normally, but sometimes it rendered in this old, buggy way. I'm wondering if this is happening due to a plugin compatibility issue.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to deactivate all plugins and see if still remains that way

Answer (score 0):

Next time it goes like this, open up Inspect Element and check the console for errors. I'm assuming it's missing the stylesheet, but as a debug step look for the actual error first.

Then the old disable all plugins and see if you can replicate the issue.

Comment: I disabled my plugins and the issue remained.I inspected element and it gave me a 500 internal server error, so I guess I should call the host provider and ask for a resolution - as it seems to be a problem on their part?